# When trying to install VirtualBox I am asked for a CD which I do not have

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, cd

Trying to install VirtualBox on 12.04 and I get a message saying to insert the following CD to continue:

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS *Precise Pangolin* - Release amd64 (20120425)

Does anyone know where I can get this CD or its contents?

Comment: At what stage of the installation? What have you done so far?

Comment: I am just trying to download it from software centre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Ubuntu was originally installed from that CD/DVD. If you still have it, put in in the drive.

Alternatively, you will need to edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment out (add a '#' character at the start) the line starting `deb cdrom:...`.

I do this using a terminal session. There may be a GUI to do this but I've never looked for one.

Comment: There is indeed a GUI ; from Software Centre, go to Edit .. Software Sources, go to the "Other" tab, and uncheck the relevant entry.

Comment: Oh I didn't realises it was that CD, I do still have it... Somewhere, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `virtualbox` from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

**OR** download the deb packages, if you're using Ubuntu 12.04, using the following links:

For i386: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.1.20/virtualbox-4.1_4.1.20-80170~Ubuntu~precise_i386.deb

For x64: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.1.20/virtualbox-4.1_4.1.20-80170~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb

If you're using some other version of Ubuntu, download virtualbox from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Go to the folder where the file was downloaded and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.1_4.1.20-80170~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb
```

Change the file name according to the version downloaded.